# Multiple thread calls to a singleton method effects local variables?

Tags: java, memory-management, methods

I created a class with multiple methods and this class can have any time only single instance,Like singleton behaviour and class not having any instance variables.

Now i'm in confusion that, If multiple calls to the a single method will give expected result or not, if the method having only parameters which will get effected by multiple threads?
Bcoz the method is in stack once the memory allocated,then simultaneously threads calls the method, what is the outcome?

Comment: If there are no instance variables, then its all good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each thread has its own, independent, private stack. When a thread enters a method, all the parameters and local variables are in that thread's local stack, and no other thread can access it.

Therefore, if two threads enter the same method, but this method only accesses its parameters and its local variables (and the parameters doesn't point to the same object in the two threads), there's no way one thread's execution could interfere with the other's thread execution. It is almost like two independent java processes.

Comment: If the method is static also, the method call to multiple threads show the same behaviour or any unexpected result?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the method is static or not. You can think of an instance method as an static method with an implicit `this` parameter, then you can reason about static and instance methods in exactly the same way.